# Ubuntu connection woes, device not showing up in lsusb any more

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, linux, mtp

I have a really weird issue in connecting my Samsung GS2 to my Ubuntu 14.04 system.

I found the ID via lsusb at first, and added a udev entry. Everything was perfect and I was happily ADBing away for a few minutes. Thereafter, I begun getting "Unable to mount samsung device" (or something similar) popups.

Since then, my GS2 doesn't even show up in lsusb. When I plug it in, the phone behaves as if it has just been connected to a wall charger; MTP doesn't work any more, while it used to fine. I've tried removing the udev config file, restarting phone and pc, and enabling/disabling debugging mode, but still there's nothing in lsusb. Everything works perfectly on my other windows machine.

What on earth is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of the symptoms you describe is that a pin is bent or broken in the USB connection. With the data pin broken but the power pin connected, the connection is exactly as if As it works on a different machine, that would narrow the problem down to the cable (if you are using different cables on each) or the USB port on your PC. Try a different cable and a different USB port.

As your phone works fine with a Windows PC, that rules out it being a problem with Android itself, so if changing the physical connection doesn't help, we probably can't help you any further here.